# Windows Server 2008 R2 Shows Event ID 137 Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Machine running HyperV, IIS, and File Server. 
Under FileSystem, Everyday morning I could find some warnings and errors happened at 4AM.
There are 11 copies of same warning.
"The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur." - Event ID: 57
The error is.
"The default transaction resource manager on volume \?\Volume{238077bf-9f39-11e1-a6b4-00188b7ad374} encountered a non-retryable error and could not start.  The data contains the error code." - Event ID: 137.
I cannot find what the real issue is. Can anybody help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: The errors are pointing to an IO issue. Are you preforming any backups to the server or virtual machines at that time?

Answer (score 0):

[www.eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-137-source-ntfs-eventno-9241-phase-1.htm) contains some suggestions related to this particular issue, including resetting the NTFS transaction log (I would be very careful doing that!). In many situations it occurs during the backup process and the backup software vendors say that it can be ignored.

Can you identify the volume specified in the event? Anything taking place at 4:00 am (scheduled tasks, etc?).